# How to copy merged branches to another branch

Tags: git

I'd like to change branches from

```
A -- B
\
 C -- D -- E -- G
      \        /
       ------F-
```

to

```
A -- B
\     \
 C     D -- E -- G
        \        /
         ------F-
```

---

`git rebase --onto B C G` will break the structure of D, E, F, G

```
A -- B -- D -- E -- F
\
 C
```

Just want to keep the structure of D, E, F, G.

How can I do it?

Comment: Should the commits D,E,F have the same project state before and after the change? Or do you expect to see a difference in the states between before-E and after-E (which would likely be the same difference that is between C and B)?

Comment: It's hard to tell from your graph whether `E` or `F` is the merge commit? (Bc E is further to the right than F.)

Comment: @TTT, updated the question. Yeah, I meant there were a merge and I'd like to keep the merge after copying them to another branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. You simply need to add the [`--rebase-merges` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---rebase-mergesrebase-cousinsno-rebase-cousins).

For example, if you change the rebase you tried:

```
git rebase --onto B C G
```

to:

```
git rebase --onto B C G --rebase-merges
```

You'll get the graph as you desire.

Note this won't always work (see my emphasized phrases in the quoted documentation below):

> By default, a rebase will simply drop merge commits from the todo list, and put the rebased commits into a single, linear branch. With `--rebase-merges`, the rebase will instead **try** to preserve the branching structure within the commits that are to be rebased, by recreating the merge commits. **Any resolved merge conflicts or manual amendments in these merge commits will have to be resolved/re-applied manually.**

The example you gave yielded a linear graph, presumably without merge conflicts. If you didn't have conflicts when you rebased without `--rebase-merges`, then you shouldn't have conflicts when you add the option.

**Tip:** Anytime you rebase, and perhaps especially when you use the `--rebase-merges` option, you can add the interactive option (`-i`) to see what the rebase is going to do before you do it. This is often useful for modifying what the rebase will do, but also just to see what's going on when you're including the merge commits so you can understand how it works behind the scenes. It also explains why you'll see something like "rebasing 1 of 11" when you include `--rebase-merges` compared to "rebasing 1 of 3" when you do a regular rebase.

Comment: I have checked with that solution, it worked. Very nice answer!. Beside `rebase --onto`, because I have not finded yet the answer ai first I also try `git cherry-pick`, anh it does not work like OPs want.

Answer (score 0):

```
A -- B              - branch t1
\
 C -- D -- E        - branch t2  
      \    /
       --F-         - branch t3
```

if rebase is not your problem, you can try:

```
git checkout t2
git rebase --onto B C
```

Update:

E is merge comit from t3 into t2, after referencing the answer of [@TTT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/184546/ttt), I add options `--rebase-merges` to prevent `git rebase --onto` break down **merge commit**.

```
git rebase --onto B C --rebase-merges
```